# How do we implement this two-valued recursive function using FunctionCompile?

Tags: functions, function-construction, recursion

I have the following recursive function that involves `DivisorSigma`:

```
r1[n_] := DivisorSigma[1, n];
r2[n_] := Sum[r1[d], {d, Divisors[n]}];
r3[n_] := Sum[r2[d], {d, Divisors[n]}];
...
```

I would like to implement the generic recursive function `r[n_,k_]` where `k` is the value of recursion dept parameter, i.e. for `k=1` we obtain `r1`, for `k=2` we obtain `r2` and so forth. I came across a relatively new feature called [FunctionCompile](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/code-compilation/compile-a-recursive-function.html?product=mathematica). I would be very grateful if anyone may help me in implementing this recursive function.

***My Background:***
I am investigating the following identity:

$$r_3(n)=\prod_{p\mid n}(3+p)\quad\text{or generally}\quad r_k(n)=\prod_{p\mid n}(k+p)$$

which is seems to be true at least for $k=2,3$:

```
p[n_, k_] := Product[p + k, {p, Complement[Divisors[n], {1, n}]}];
Print[r2[10]];
Print[p[10, 2]];
Print[r3[10]];
Print[p[10, 3]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Not an answer but an extended comment

One solution to the generalized approach is using `Divisors`'s `Listable` feature:

```
ClearAll[fn];

fn[n_, k_] := Total[Nest[Catenate@*Divisors, {n}, k]]
```

But you could not use `FunctionCompile`. The `Divisors` is not compilable (in `FunctionCompile` not `Compile`) as of now (version 13.0.1) unless somebody came up with an undocumented or manual version.

Another example:

```
r3[10000] // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {0.0007438, 120285} *)

fn[10000, 3] // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {0.0007075, 120285} *)
```

We could use `Compile`:

```
fnCompiled = 
 Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}}, 
  Total[Nest[Catenate@*Divisors, {n}, k]], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Compare:

```
r3[10000] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {0.000844, 2584} *)

fn[10000, 3] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {0.0006784, 51208} *)

fnCompiled[10000, 3] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {0.0005641, 48256} *)
```

Note that this approach will expand `k` level then sum all those numbers up, so if you choose large numbers, you'll see the effect:

```
fn[500, 10]
(* Out: 68730 *)

(* AbsoluteTiming: 0.0295315 *)
(* MaxMemoryUsed:  1508424   *)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using now your `Compile` variant, which works great.